# How do you set up your client on Braintree

Tags: javascript, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I am trying to create my client but am confused on what to do with all the javascript code which is being given to me. I want to create a Drop-in UI. I have successfully been able to generate a client token by using `$clientToken = $gateway->clientToken()->generate();` I am not using a customerID to keep track of customers.

My question is, in the step `Get a client token` in the [docs here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v3). Where do I put the javascript code now? I have no idea where to put:

```
braintree.dropin.create({
  // Step three: get client token from your server, such as via
 //    templates or async http request
  authorization: CLIENT_TOKEN_FROM_SERVER,
  container: '#dropin-container'
}, (error, dropinInstance) => {
  // Use `dropinInstance` here
  // Methods documented at https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web-drop-in/docs/current/Dropin.html
});
```

And also in the javascript it says `Use dropinInstance here` How do I make a dropinInstance? If anyone could tell me how to complete the client set up, that would be fantastic

Here is my code so far:

### index.php

```
<?php require_once('Braintree.php');

$gateway = new Braintree\Gateway([
    'environment' => 'sandbox',
    'merchantId' => 'use_your_merchant_id',
    'publicKey' => 'use_your_public_key',
    'privateKey' => 'use_your_private_key'
]);

$clientToken = $gateway->clientToken()->generate();

?>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.25.0/js/dropin.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Step one: add an empty container to your page -->
    <div id="dropin-container"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Step two: create a dropin instance using that container (or a string
        //   that functions as a query selector such as `#dropin-container`)
        braintree.dropin.create({
          container: document.getElementById('dropin-container'),
          // ...plus remaining configuration
        }, (error, dropinInstance) => {
          // Use `dropinInstance` here
          // Methods documented at https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web-drop-in/docs/current/Dropin.html
        });
    </script>
</body>
```